# Dynamically add Keys From Array Content

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

How can I add fields dynamically in MongoDB? I have an array, with which I want to create columns. For example, from this,

```
/* 1 */
{
    "date" : "2017-07-30",
    "brand" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Apple",
            "quantity" : 31
        }
    ],
    "total" : 31
}

/* 2 */
{
    "date" : "2017-08-02",
    "brand" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Apple",
            "quantity" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Samsung",
            "quantity" : 6
        }
    ],
    "total" : 7
}
```

I want to make this,

```
/* 1 */
{
    "date" : "2017-07-30",
    "Apple": 31,
    "Samsung": 0,
    "total" : 31
}

/* 2 */
{
    "date" : "2017-08-02",
    "Apple": 1,
    "Samsung": 6,
    "total" : 7
}
```

There `$addFields` operator can add a field, but how can I use it for multiple fields?

Comment: extremely sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it, but honestly it's kind of a waste. Use [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) and [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) where you have it:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": {
      "$arrayToObject": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          [{ "k": "date", "v": "$date" }],
          { "$map": {
            "input": "$brand",
            "as": "b",
            "in": { "k": "$$b.name", "v": "$$b.quantity" }
          }},
          [{ "k": "total", "v": "$total" }]
        ]
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

It's actually a lot better to simply transform from the cursor. As in the shell:

```
db.collection.find().map( doc =>
  Object.assign(
    { date: doc.date },
    doc.brand.map(d => ({ [d.name]: d.quantity }) )
      .reduce((acc,curr) => Object.assign(acc,curr),{}),
    { total: doc.total }
  )
)
```

Which does the same thing:

```
[
    {
        "date" : "2017-07-30",
        "Apple" : 31.0,
        "total" : 31.0
    },
    {
        "date" : "2017-08-02",
        "Apple" : 1.0,
        "Samsung" : 6.0,
        "total" : 7.0
    }
]
```